# Allow a textbox to take zero as first number

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox

I have this telephone number textbox that I want to allow users to be able to enter a zero as the first number as per area code.

e.g. 0720-123-456

[image]

In my program, when I click save, The zero gets omitted and gets saved as

[image]

in my MySQL database that has an INT field. I have validated the textbox key press event to only allow numbers.

How can I make users be able to save numbers starting with zero?

Comment: Change your database field to text datatype. Phone numbers should be saved as strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution of your problme is

Change data type of column `INT` to `Varchar`

---

other solution is format you fetched integer value i.e. after fetching phone number from the database format it properly using `ToString method and formater` But this is not recommended solution

Answer (score 1):

may this code give u any type of hint

```
if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("0"))
                {
                    // your code
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("number should be start with 0");
                }
            }
```